# Query to get count of periods in current month

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have a tabl pay_time_period with following detail

```
PAYROLL_ID              START_DATE          END_DATE                PERIOD_NUM
10                      01-MAY-2023         10-MAY-2023             1
10                      11-MAY-2023         18-MAY-2023             2
10                      19-MAY-2023         25-MAY-2023             3
10                      26-MAY-2023         05-JUN-2023             4
```

Now i need to find the number of periods in the month of the parameter date passed. How to tweak the below query

```
(select distinct 
COUNT(ptp1.PERIOD_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY ptp1.PAYROLL_ID,papf.person_number) period_count
from pay_time_periods ptp1
where ptp1.TIME_PERIOD_ID = ptp.TIME_PERIOD_ID
and :p_process_date between ptp1.start_Date and ptp1.end_date
)
```

The outcome should come as 4. since in may there are are 4 period_num

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ptp1.PERIOD_NUM)
from pay_time_periods ptp1
where ptp1.TIME_PERIOD_ID = ptp.TIME_PERIOD_ID
    and :p_process_date between ptp1.start_Date and ptp1.end_date
GROUP BY ptp1.PAYROLL_ID
```

Comment: hey this will still give the count one, I want the total count in the month of the parameter passed, so 4 in above case

Comment: @SSA_Tech124 could you check now?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ptp.PERIOD_NUM) AS period_count
FROM pay_time_period ptp
WHERE ptp.START_DATE <= LAST_DAY(:p_process_date)
AND ptp.END_DATE >= TRUNC(:p_process_date, 'MM')
```